# JavaScript question -- onMouseOver event

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

Why doesn't this piece of code swap images on mouse-over as intended?:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="
 if (document.the_image.src == '01.jpg')
 {
  document.the_image.src = '02.jpg';
 }
 else if (document.the_image.src == '02.jpg')
 {
  document.the_image.src = '03.jpg';
 }
 else
 {
  document.the_image.src = '01.jpg';
 }
 ">
Some image</a><br>
```

Comment: what is the `the_image` property of document object?

Comment: Jonathan, I tried to post the complete tidbit of the code but I kept getting this message from the website:

" Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn 10 reputation to post images. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely in the rendered HTML, the image source is an absolute URL, so the **src** is probably **"http://mydomain.com/01.jpg"**

To test this, try setting an **alert()** in your code to see what the actual **src** value is

You should probably also put that code in a function, that's a lot of javascript to put in inline HTML.

Comment: +1 for the solution and for working in Hawai. I wish I were there :-)

Comment: jaywon, your comments make a lot of sense to me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @jaywon answer, if that is the case you can use this to ensure that it is matching regardless of absolute or relative URL.

```
if (document.the_image.src.indexOf('01.jpg') > 0) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've figured out how to post the complete code. Thanks very much!:

```
<HTML>
<head>

<title></title>
<script language="javascript">
    var name = prompt('What is your name?', '');
    document.writeln('Welcome, ' + name + '.');
</script>
</head>


<body>

<a href="#" onMouseOver="
    if (document.the_image.src == '01.jpg')
    {
        document.the_image.src = '02.jpg';
    }
    else if (document.the_image.src == '02.jpg')
    {
        document.the_image.src = '03.jpg';
    }
    else
    {
        document.the_image.src = '01.jpg';
    }
    ">
<img src="01.jpg" name="the_image"></a><br>


</body>

</HTML>
```